# SQL syntax to retrieve votes strangely misses some results

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I've tried to look other posts to do a Mysql query, I think I'm almost there but for some reason I have a bug.

I have those tables :

```
POSTS [id_post (int) / activity (int) ]
VOTES [id_vote (int) / id_post (int) / user_id (int)]
ACTIVITIES [id_activity (int) / activity_name (varchar)]
```

I have in fact more tables and fields than that, but these are the relevant one for my problem. I created a vote system that adds a user vote to the VOTES table, refering to the post that is being voted and the user account of the voting person.

So the votes table may look like this :

```
id_vote | id_post | user_id
   1        5         8
   2        6         8
```

Every post belongs to an activity. I would like to lists the posts which have the most votes for each activity.

That's where I am so far :

```
SELECT activities.id_activity, activities.activity_name, votes.id_post, votes.totalvotes AS allvotes
FROM ( SELECT votes.id_post, COUNT(*) as totalvotes
       FROM `votes`
       GROUP BY votes.id_post
     ) AS votes
JOIN posts ON posts.id_post = votes.id_post
JOIN activities ON posts.activity = activities.id_activity
GROUP BY activities.id_activity
HAVING allvotes = MAX(totalvotes)
```

This works well, I retrieve what I want except that if 2 posts in the same activity have the same amount of votes, I have no idea which one only appears after grouping those posts, and why it's not the other one.

```
id_activity | activity_name | id_post | allvotes
    5            eating          5         2
    3           sleeping         6         1
```

More importantly, what is really bugging me is that some activities won't show up for some reason. I noticed that, in the above example, if the post 5 belonging to the eating category is the one that has the most votes indeed, then the category appears. BUT if it happens that the post for the eating category which have the mosts votes IS NOT post 5 (which is the one MYSQL decided to show up by default), the the whole row about the eating category just WON'T SHOW UP at all.

It's been 2 days I'm on this...
Any ideas ?

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is little complex to implement in a single query. it will be easy with some temporary tables. if you want it in a single query then you can try with row_number.

example:

```
SELECT id_activity,activity_name,id_post,v_count FROM(
SELECT id_activity,activity_name,id_post,v_count 
,@rownum := IF(@prev_value=id_activity,@rownum+1,1) AS RowNumber
,@prev_value := id_activity  
FROM (
select a.id_activity,a.activity_name,p.id_post,v.v_count
from activities a
left join posts p on p.activity=a.id_activity
left join (
  select id_post,count(*) v_count from votes v1
  group by id_post
) v on v.id_post=p.id_post
order by a.id_activity, v.v_count desc) as tmp
,(SELECT @rownum := 0) r
,(SELECT @prev_value := '') y
)tmp2
WHERE rownumber=1
```

[FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e53013/126)

Comment: REALLY thanks a lot. 2 days on this, and you solve the problem directly ! You're a boss ! Although I really didn't understand how you did it (I don't know about the @rownum syntax and meaning.

One question though. Sinc I see like 6 selects on this query, and you say an alternative is to use a temporary table, would you recommand using this query or the temporary table ? I have no idea how I would do this one either, but I could consider if it's faster ?

Thanks a bunch anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

i guess its because you group by the activity, i wonder why this statement is allowed in mysql, in mssql you are not allowed to group only by activities.id_activity in this case, you had to group by activity and/or id_post

try this:

```
SELECT activities.id_activity, activities.activity_name, votes.id_post, COUNT(*) as totalvotes
FROM votes
INNER JOIN posts ON posts.id_post = votes.id_post
INNER JOIN activities ON posts.activity = activities.id_activity
GROUP BY votes.id_post
HAVING totalvotes = MAX(totalvotes)
```

and lmk if it works :)

or your statement modified:

```
SELECT activities.id_activity, activities.activity_name, votes.id_post, votes.totalvotes AS allvotes
FROM ( SELECT votes.id_post, COUNT(*) as totalvotes
       FROM `votes`
       GROUP BY votes.id_post
     ) AS votes
JOIN posts ON posts.id_post = votes.id_post
JOIN activities ON posts.activity = activities.id_activity
GROUP BY votes.id_post
HAVING allvotes = MAX(totalvotes)
```

if i get you right then its because you have 2 posts with the same activity, as soon as you group the activities and not group the posts, one post disappears.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast answer, I appreciate.
I tried both solutions, but none actually work right now. The first one returns no results, while the second guess return many result but many rows show posts from the same activity.

If I group by activity_id, I do have only one post of each activity showing, although it's not the good one. If I group by post_id, I don't get what I need, and if I group by activity AND then id_post, it stills shows many rows from the same category.

I also tried the HAVING part exactly like you suggested, it works fine except for some activities not appearing